# insert necesarry file to visible table in rgbDiv section

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

So I trying to display hidden division/section after user upload necessary file (in this case 3 files) but where do I need to use onchange javascript?
here mine so far

html

```
<body onload="rgbOrMulti()"> 
<div style="padding: 14px 16px;">
<form action="/action_page.php">
<p>Red tif</p>
<input type="file" name="RedBand" accept=".tif" id="redBand" onchange="rgbOrMulti()">
</form>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<p>Green tif</p>
<input type="file" name="GreenBand" accept=".tif" id="greenBand" onchange="rgbOrMulti()">
</form>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<p>Blue tif</p>
<input type="file" name="BlueBand" accept=".tif" id="blueBand" onchange="rgbOrMulti()">     
</div>

<div id="rgbDiv">
<form action="/action_page.php">
<p>Red tif</p>
<input type="text" name="filename" accept=".tif">
</form>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<p>Green tif</p>
<input type="text" name="filename" accept=".tif">
</form>
<form action="/action_page.php">
<p>Blue tif</p>
<input type="text" name="filename" accept=".tif">       
</div>
</body>
```

javascript

```
function rgbOrMulti() {
    if (document.getElementById('redBand').files.length != 0 && getElementById('greenBand').files.length != 0 && getElementById('blueBand').files.length != 0) {
      alert(blueBand.value);
        document.getElementById('rgbDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('multiDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if(document.getElementById('redtif').files.length != 0 && document.getElementById('greentif').files.length != 0 && document.getElementById('bluetif').files.length != 0) {
      document.getElementById('multiDiv').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('rgbDiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else{
      // none file insert 
    }
  }
```

how do i onchange the division rgbDiv to to visible properly??

Answer (score 0):

You try to set the visibility of these elements to visible with JavaScript, but your css still hiding them with display:none.

Either remove your css, or change the display property instead of visibility

Comment: then how to want the division to stay hidden till user insert necessary file then it be visible?

Comment: change your css to default visibility hidden for those elements.

Comment: #rgbDiv{visibility: hidden;} ? but still cant unhidden it after insert the files